# Pass class to record

Tags: delphi, class, record

I want define constant with records where one variable is class.
And receive error:
**[DCC Error] usample.pas(18): E2026 Constant expression expected**

Class and record declaration in **Unit1**:

```
type TParentClass = class (TObject)
 function Call(s: string) : boolean;
end;

type TMyRecord = record
 s: string;
 c: TParentClass; //or TClass
end;
```

And **Unit2** with Child Class and record:

```
type TChildClass = class (TParentClass);
 procedure two;

var:
  class_var: TChildClass;

const
 rec_var : array[0..1] of TMyRecord = (
   (s : ''; c : class_var) //Error with class_var.
 );
```

**UPD:** I want to fill record with Class and in unit1 search functions in this Class. Its a team project.

**UPD2:**

```
const 
  class_var: TChildClass = nil;
```

Same error.

Comment: This simply cannot be done. A constant can only contain constants.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where would `class_var` be set?

Answer (score 2):

Because as the compiler says, you have to put a constant in there, but you defined class_var as a variable.

Change class_var to be declared as a constant, not a variable.

**But this cannot actually be done:**

```
const
  class_var  = TParentClass;
```

is not allowed.

And

```
const
  class_var : TClass = TParentClass;
```

is not a **real** constant and you cannot use it inside another constant declaration.

Comment: @Françoisvar:
const
  class_var: TChildClass = nil;
Same error.

Comment: @МиколаРоманюк, see my update. You need a **"real"** constant there.

Comment: @Françoisvar: So may I try use pointer at Class beetween of class constant?

Answer (score 2):

In your latest update you ask why this does not compile:

```
const 
  class_var: TChildClass = nil;

rec_var: TMyRecord = (s: ''; c: class_var);
```

The reason that does not compile is that `class_var` is not a [true constant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#True_Constants). You can write it like this:

```
rec_var: TMyRecord = (s: ''; c: nil);
```

because `nil` is a true constant.

I'm struggling to get a handle on what you are really trying to do, but my instincts tell me that a constant is not what you need. I think you are going to need to use variables that are initialized at startup.

Comment: Yes, it's work but I need to change nil to created class variable thet require function that also must be passed to record.

Comment: I suppose op meant that , could the pointer be const , so the class pointer won't change, however the class itself could change.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a const with a field initialized to the content of a variable.  The compiler needs to evaluate consts at compile time, ie when class_var does not even have a location, never mind any content.

Forget this idea.  If you can, declare rec_var as a variable and load it up at runtime.